# convert hh:mm:ss:fff to ss.fff in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string like 00:00:01:347(hh:mm:ss:fff) which denotes the time in milliseconds.
I want to convert it to 01.347(totalsecond.fff).

I tried below code to execute

```
string time = "00:00:01:347:789";
int index = time.LastIndexOf(":");
if (index > 0)
    time = time.Substring(0, index);
double seconds = TimeSpan.Parse(time).TotalSeconds;
```

but it is giving exception in last line.
it would be great if someone could help me on this.

Comment: Your `time` string also appears to have microsecond components.  What do you want to do with them?

Comment: I bet the exception tells you what problem you are having... So basically your only problem is how to parse that string, as you already know how to get it in s.fff format once you have a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: I don't want to do anything with microsecond. I have already removed it from the string.

Comment: the exception says Sytem.OverflowException. Could you please write a code of how to convert hh:mm:ss:fff into ss.fff?

Comment: try to output this one. `TimeSpan.Parse(time).ToString()`. what is the result?

Comment: You have that error because `TimeSpan` is finding three `:`, which is non-standard. You either replace the one just before the milliseconds with a dot, or use John's approach.

Comment: Or even better, use `TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "hh:mm:ss:fff*" , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TotalSeconds`. There is no wildcard character for `ParseExact`, so you have to trim the string beforehand, like you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

You can parse the string to `DateTime` first using `ParseExact` and get the timespan using `TimeOfDay` property.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string time = "00:00:01:347"; // I removed the microsecond for brevity
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "hh:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.WriteLine(dt.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds); // 01.347(totalsecond.fff)

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

EDIT: As stated by @Andrew, here's another solution.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "hh\\:mm\\:ss\\:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalSeconds); // 01.347
```

Note that you have to escape the separators to avoid getting FormatException.

Comment: For the record, you could better use `TimeSpan.ParseExact` instead and then `dt.TotalSeconds`.